# Clear/Remove Usage of Angular App service variables dependencies from Application components

Tags: javascript, rxjs, angular7

I have Single Page Application(SPA) Angular7 configured with Angular cli.
This is large application with different-different Angular Services ,including global and component level too.

Application Components using Services,I/O event,emitter for communication between different components.

So please suggestion and guide me to remove at least 50 percentage Service variable usage inside component.
For example see below code service variable using inside component.

But here i facing problem each services having more than handards of public variables.And these Service public level declared variable also using in different-different component.And also variables in one component coming with value and in other component value is coming undefine if i will go with application routing.

Any other better approach i can use instead of declaring service variable and accessing inside components.

Please any help.

**AppService.ts**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AppService {

public isApplicationInitialized=false;
..
...

}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {AppService} from './AppService'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent {

  title = 'App';

  constructor(public appService:AppService){
  this.appService.isApplicationInitialized=true;
  ...
  ..
  }  

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular services are very powerful tool. They allow you to inject dependencies into components or other services (service depends on another service).

Basically, they are here to allow you manage your data in a decoupled way: A component needs to fetch/save some data? Instead of fetching it inside the component, inject some relevant service and get data via that service. Your component should focus on its business only which is presening and interacting with the user.

With services, component can share data without actually know each other.

providers settings (in AppModule or Components declaration) can further configure how your services are injected and consumed.

Saying that, you can abuse this option and structure your app poorly leading to cumbersome coding and lots of irrelevant services.

My suggestion to you is to see the 'big picture' of your project first, then structure it accordingly to data-domains, so it'll be clearer where each data is located and which service is responsible for it.
It's very common to see component constructor with lots of dependencies, don't feel bad about that.